# Retrieve date(only) column as string or map to string without time using Prisma ORM

Tags: typescript, date, prisma

I'm using Prisma2 (`prisma @prisma/client`).

In my underlying postgres db I have a column of type `date`, i.e. date only without time.

Prisma returns for this column a Javascript `Date` object (https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/preview-features/native-types/native-types-mappings#datetime), which carries time information as well.

After serializing I end up with a full ISO string of date and time. However, I'd only like to return the date part (time part will always be 00:00:00).

At the moment I do:

```
return await prisma.entity.findMany().map(e => ({ ...e, date: e.date.toISOString().substring(0,10) }))
```

I'd like to get rid of the manual mapping as I have to repeat it for every query and the mapping gets more complicated for nested queries etc. pp.

Does Prisma support some kind of transformation (e.g. using class-transformer) that is added to the model (and automagically performed)? I haven't found anything in the docs. Or can I teach Prisma to return this column as a string, not a Date object?

Answer (score 4):

Prisma Client is returning JavaScript `Date` objects [by design](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/preview-features/native-types/native-types-mappings#clients-6), unfortunately this can not be configured in the Prisma Client API.

As a workaround, you could consider writing a [middleware](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware) function that automatically converts `Date` objects to strings so that you don't need to do it manually in your application time every time you're working with a `Date`.

If you'd like to see this natively supported by Prisma, feel free to [open a feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=) with your use case so that our team can look into this.

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan! I understand it is by design. In case of date-only column I don't find the JavaScript `Date` object suitable. Could also be, that users prefer to work with a date library of their choice. Will look into middlewares. Thanks!

Comment: You can directly pass `Date` object to any date library like `moment` or `date-fns`. I would like to know if you have any specific use case that you are looking for.

Comment: I know. And I learned that I can write a middleware, that automatically does this conversion for me :-)
I'm coming from TypeORM and really liked to have a declarative way to express this conversion in the model, rather than writing a middleware.
My use case is that I need to store and handle time series with one value per day.

Answer (score 0):

you can use middware to retrieve a string, but if you do like this, your type of this field is still a "Datetime" in schema, which will limit your handles of this field using Datetime APIs!